# Bool tool brush question

Tags: modeling, modifiers

After using bool tool,brush boolean difference,
how to make brush object stay for another difference bool?

Now, when I apply brush boolean difference, brush object is gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make the brush object active after *Difference* brush was added and apply it only for the brush it will remain undeleted, just its *Maximum Draw Type* will be set to *Bounds* (it will return to *Textured* once *Difference* brush is removed from the object). However the final effect of the brush will be applied to the canvas.

[image: GIF-bool-tool]